# Тире, тире с запятой или двоеточие?

Tags: пунктуация

Зажмурился, от страха дышать не мог, а как распахнул глаза — тишина.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно: Зажмурился, от страха дышать не мог, а как распахнул глаза — тишина. 
Тире ставится между двумя сказуемыми и между двумя независимыми предложениями, если во втором из них содержится неожиданное присоединение или резкое противопоставление по отношению к первому, например:

```
Я вышел, не желая его обидеть, на террасу -  и обомлел.
```

Подробнее здесь: http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/?rub=tire

Comment: А с чего Вы, собственно, взяли, что в данном случае есть какое-то резкое противопоставление? ;)

Comment: Не противопоставление - неожиданность.

Answer (score 2):

Можно считать, что это БСП, тире указывает на неожиданный результат действия или быструю смену событий. Второе предложение является назывным.

Для сравнения: Не успел я моргнуть — мяч уже в воротах.

Answer (score 0):

Прежде всего, в данном предложении мы видим однородные члена предложения (однородные сказуемые): зажмурился, не мог дышать (составное глагольное сказуемое), распахнул.

Итак, в данном случае у нас идёт перечисление однородных членов предложения, не связанных союзами. Посему в таких случаях ставится запятая между ними.

А вот тире, конечно же, меня слегка смутило. Могу лишь предположить, что это неполное предложение с пропущенным сказуемым (в таких предложениях, насколько я знаю, всегда отсутствует именно сказуемое). Тире заменило сказуемое «виднелась».

Но тут что-то странное.

Союз «Как» может передавать временной оттенок, насколько я знаю. Следовательно, если бы тире отсутствовало (то есть предложение было бы полным), то оно выглядело бы так: А как распахнул глаза, виднелась тишина (или же «показалась»).

Предполагаю, что на основе этого следует использовать и тире, и запятую.

Мой вариант: *Зажмурился, от страха дышать не мог, а как распахнул глаза, — тишина.*

Хотя тоже крайне странно выглядит. Давайте-ка подождём профессионалов.